# "ImportError: cannot import name ..." - raised on "import from" but not on direct import

Tags: python, import, python-3.x, importerror

What is the precise rule under which this exception is raised by Python 3 interpreter?

There are plenty of SO questions about that, with excellent answers, but I could not find one that gave a clear, general, and logically precise definition of the circumstances when this exception occurs.

The documentation doesn't seem to be clear either. It says:

> exception `ImportError`
>
> > Raised when an import statement fails to find
> >     the module definition or when a `from ... import` fails to find a name
> >     that is to be imported.

But this seems inconsistent with the following example.

I meant to ask for a general definition rather than a specific case, but to clarify my concerns, here's an example:

```
# code/t.py:
from code import d

# code/d.py
from code import t
```

Running module `t.py` from the command line results in `ImportError: cannot import name d`.

On the other hand, the following code doesn't raise exceptions:

```
# code/t.py:
import code.d

# code/d.py
import code.t
```

At all times, `__init__.py` is empty.

In this example, the only modules or names mentioned in the import statement are `t` and `d`, and they were both clearly found. If the documentation implies that some name *within* the `d` module isn't found, it's certainly not obvious; and on top of that, I'd expect it to raise `NameError: name ... is not defined` exception rather than `ImportError`.

Comment: "Sometimes this code:..results in an `ImportError` exception"? So sometimes it works and other times it doesn't. What's different between the two?

Comment: @martineau: reworded.. nothing is different, the same code in both cases, except for this one line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `abc` is a package and `xyz` is a module, and if `abc`'s `__init__.py` defines an `__all__` that does not include `xyz`, then you won't be able to do `from abc import xyz`, but you'll still be able to do `import abc.xyz`.

Edit: The short answer is: your problem is that your imports are circular.  Modules t and d try to import each other.  This won't work.  Don't do it.  I'm going to explain the whole thing, below but the explanation is pretty long.

To understand why it gives an ImportError, try to follow the code execution.  If you look at the full traceback instead of just the final part, you can see what it's doing.  With your setup I get a traceback like this (I called the package "testpack" instead of "code"):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 1, in <module>
    from testpack import d
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\BrenBarn\My Documents\Python\testpack\d.py", line 1, in <module>
    from testpack import t
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\BrenBarn\My Documents\Python\testpack\t.py", line 1, in <module>
    from testpack import d
ImportError: cannot import name d
```

You can see what Python is doing here.

1. In loading `t.py`, the first thing it sees is `from testpack import d`.
2. At that point, Python executes the `d.py` file to load that module.
3. But the first thing it finds there is `from testpack import t`.
4. It already is loading `t.py` once, but t as the main script is different than t as a module, so it tries to load `t.py` again.
5. The first thing it sees is `from testpack import d`, which would mean it should try to load `d.py` . . . but it already *was* trying to load `d.py` back in step 2.  Since trying to import `d` led back to trying to import `d` again, Python realizes it can't import `d` and throws ImportError.

Step 4 is kind of anomalous here because you ran a file in the package directly, which isn't the usual way to do things.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python) for an explanation of why importing a module is different from running it directly.  If you try to *import* `t` instead (with `from testpack import t`), Python realizes the circularity one step sooner, and you get a simpler traceback:

```
>>> from testpack import t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from testpack import t
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\BrenBarn\My Documents\Python\testpack\t.py", line 1, in <module>
    from testpack import d
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\BrenBarn\My Documents\Python\testpack\d.py", line 1, in <module>
    from testpack import t
ImportError: cannot import name t
```

Notice that here the error is that it can't import *t*.  It knows it can't, because when I told it to import t, it found itself looping back to import t again.  In your original example, it didn't notice it was running t.py twice, because the first time was the main script and the second was an import, so it took one more step and tried to import d again.

Now, why doesn't this happen when you do `import code.d`?  The answer is just because you don't actually try to *use* the imported modules  In this case, it happens as follows (I'm going to explain as if you did `from code import t` rather than running it as a script):

1. It starts to import t.  When it does this, it provisionally marks the module `code.t` as imported, even though it's not done importing yet.
2. It finds it has to do `import code.d`, so it runs d.
3. In d, it finds `import code.t`, but since `code.t` is already marked as imported, it doesn't try to import it again.
4. Since d finished without actually using `t`, it gets to go back and finish loading `t`.  No problem.

The key difference is that the names `t` and `d` are not directly accessible to each other here; they are mediated by the package `code`, so Python doesn't actually have to finish "deciding what t is" until it is actually used.  With `from code import t`, since the value has to be assigned to the variable `t`, Python has to know what it is right away.

You can see the problem, though if you make `d.py` look like this:

```
import code.t
print code.t
```

Now, after step 2, while running d, it actually tries to access the half-imported module t.  This will raise an AttributeError because, since the module hasn't been fully imported yet, it hasn't been attached to the package `code`.

Note that it would be fine as long as the use of `code.t` didn't happen until after `d` finished running.  This will work fine in `d.py`:

```
import code.t
def f():
    print code.t
```

You can call `f` later and it will work.  The reason is that it doesn't need to use `code.t` until after `d` finished executing, and after d finishes executing, it can go back and finish executing t.

To reiterate, the main moral of the story is **don't use circular imports**.  It leads to all kinds of headaches.  Instead, factor out common code into a third module imported by both modules.

Comment: Thank you, this is good to know! But in my case, all `__init__.py` files are empty. If it helps, I can copy the exact code that causes the problem, but since I'm looking for a general rule rather than a solution to a specific problem, I am not sure it's relevant.

Comment: @max: If you can provide a simple example that would certainly be helpful.

Comment: @max: I have edited with a short answer and a long explanation.  The short answer is: the problem is that your imports are circular.

Answer (score 1):

```
from abc import xyz
```

is equivalent to doing

```
xyz = __import__('abc').xyz
```

Since if you merely `import abc`, `abc.xyz` won't exist without a separate import (unless `abc/__init__.py` contains an explicit `import` for `xyz`), what you're seeing is expected behavior.

Comment: But in the second case (the one that doesn't raise exception), I am doing `import abc.xyz` not `import abc`.

Comment: @max `abc.xyz` is a separate module from `abc`, and importing one doesn't implicitly import the other, in either direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `abc` is a predefined  standard library module and just creating a subdirectory of that same name with an `__init__.py` in it doesn't change that fact. Change the name of your package to something else by renaming the folder the `__init__.py` file is in to something different, i.e. to `def`, and then both forms of `import` should execute without error.

Comment: I'm so sorry, it was a terrible example on my part. I didn't actually use `abc`, I just used it in my question. I'll remember never to use it in the actual code :)